# PygameRaspberry pi fails

Tags: python, audio, pygame, raspberry-pi, microphone

I'm working with a raspberry pi in Python, and I need to get audio from a USB microphone but also to play audio with a speaker and Pygame. I'm using an external-powered speaker conected to the raspberry jack.
To use the usb mic I have to change `options snd-usb-audio index=-2` to `options snd-usb-audio index=0` in `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`
With this the usb mic works, and I can play music from the terminal using aplay for example. But when I try to use Pygame i get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "program.py", line 5, in <module>
    pygame.mixer.init()
pygame.error: No available audio device
```

How could I fix this error? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After researching for a little bit, I came up with a solution.

Try adding the line `options snd_bcm2835 index=1` after `options snd-usb-audio index=0` in `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`. I had a similar problem involving audio on the Raspberry Pi, and if it doesn't work, I recommend getting a 3.5 mm adapter that supports both input and output, as the Pi only supports output. I've tried using USB before, and it seems that the 3.5 mm jack is a lot better.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I've tried this but it still doesn't work. It doesn't give any errors but doesn't load

Comment: So it fixed only one thing really.. now there's no errors? If that's the case than the script did something, but if not then I'm not too sure. You may wan to try the Raspberry Pi Stack Exchange or forums. I can't think of anything else to solve the problem.

Comment: I've tried re-installing raspbian, but now I also get this:
`ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1018:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "program.py", line 6, in <module>
    pygame.mixer.init()
pygame.error: No available audio device
`